# Sequence Grabber

Tags: macos, quicktime

I am looking to list out All Capture Devices in mac by using Sequence grabber.
I add QuickTime Framework and QuickTimeComponents.h,  but Still i have error

```
unknown type name SeqGrabComponent
```

Answer (score 5):

The Sequence Grabber and the whole QuickTime C API has been removed in 64-bit.  Go into your project settings and set your app's architecture to be 32-bit and see if that helps. 
-Ken

Comment: I changed architecture from 64 bit to 32-bit and got build successfully .But still i have errors in my code. how to remove that errors? please help me

Comment: My project build successfully without any error after open xcode fresh. thankz

Comment: I have Problem in 64-bit and 32-bit in mac. i am using mac10.6 version.it support 64-bit default. when i run my project in terminal using makefile ,how to run 32bit and 64 bit api's separately? why some Framework api available only in 32-bit(lower version)? please clear my doubt.